# How to extend Android's SimpleCursorAdapter?

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

I would like to extend SimpleCursorAdapter, to add an `} else if (c instanceof MyView) { setMyViewMyThing(MyView v, text)` to the `bindView` method.

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    final ViewBinder binder = mViewBinder;
    final int count = mTo.length;
    final int[] from = mFrom;
    final int[] to = mTo;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final View v = view.findViewById(to[i]);
        if (v != null) {
            boolean bound = false;
            if (binder != null) {
                bound = binder.setViewValue(v, cursor, from[i]);
            }

            if (!bound) {
                String text = cursor.getString(from[i]);
                if (text == null) {
                    text = "";
                }

                if (v instanceof TextView) {
                    setViewText((TextView) v, text);
                } else if (v instanceof ImageView) {
                    setViewImage((ImageView) v, text);
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(v.getClass().getName() + " is not a " +
                            " view that can be bounds by this SimpleCursorAdapter");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The fact that `mViewBinder`, `mTo` and `mFrom` are private members of SimpleCursorAdpater prevents me from doing this.

Is there a better way to achieve my objective than to copy the source of `SimpleCursorAdapter` wholesale into a `MyCursorView` and add my condition to `bindView`?  (That solution will work, and will be quick, but reeks of bad practise.)

(On a meta-level, it looks like the Android authors have traded my freedom to extend SimpleCursorAdapter for their freedom to change the implementation.  Is there any language which can preserve both?)

Comment: shouldn't you set a custom binder instead ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to extend Android's SimpleCursorView?

There is no `SimpleCursorView` in Android. For the rest of this answer, I will presume that you are referring [to `SimpleCursorAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html).

> I would like to extend SimpleCursorView, to add an } else if (c instanceof MyView) { setMyViewMyThing(MyView v, text) to the bindView method.

Everybody else would [use `setViewBinder()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#setViewBinder%28android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder%29) to supply [their own `ViewBinder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html). Quoting the documentation for `ViewBinder`:

> You should use this class to bind values from the Cursor to views that are not directly supported by SimpleCursorAdapter or to change the way binding occurs for views supported by SimpleCursorAdapter.

Of course, you do not have to do this.

> Is there a better way to achieve my objective than to copy the source of SimpleCursorView wholesale into a MyCursorView and add my condition to bindView?

Besides using `ViewBinder`? Probably not.

> On a meta-level, it looks like the Android authors have traded my freedom to extend SimpleCursorView for their freedom to change the implementation.

"On a meta-level", it looks like the Android authors [favored composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Comment: Thanks, you're completely right, I had overlooked `ViewBinder`.  Extending `ResourceCursorAdapter` looks more straightforward that using `ViewBinder`, so I'll give that a try first.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to achieve should be feasible with a [SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html).  Implement one of these, and return `false` in the `setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex)` function if `view` is not an instance of your `MyView`.  Then, call `SimpleCursorAdapter.setViewBinder(SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder viewBinder)`, passing your `ViewBinder` as parameter.  According to the documentation (and the implementation you posted),  if the `ViewBinder` cannot handle the `View` type (i.e. it returns `false`), `bindView()` will fall back to the default implementation.